# What is difference between Ruby and Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-hosting

What is difference between Ruby and Ruby on Rails? OK, I know that Ruby on Rails is a Web app framework that is built on the scripting language Ruby.

But why are there options on godaddy.com to choose hosting for Ruby and hosting for Ruby on Rails?
Would it be the same to put hosting for C# and for asp.net?

You can check it [here](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/popups/language_support.aspx?prog_id=GoDaddy&tab=languages&ci=8845)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I would guess it's a marketing thing/trick as far as GoDaddy is concerned.

There are other frameworks written in Ruby besides Rails, [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) for example, and you can very well write your web applications without framework (your own server, does exactly what you need it to do).

Although, all of that, including Rails, can be named `Ruby hosting`.

Answer (score 2):

Krule's on the money. The difference is between a language and a framework. Ruby, the programming language, can be used to support any number of web and application frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

By their wording, it's safe to say that it's more of a marketing reason using the ruby on rails buzz word.

Other than that it could mean default support for all the necessary tools for common ruby on rails development scenarios.